# How to empty an inputstream?

Tags: java, io

I have a device that I communicate with via inputstreams.

Now the problem is the following:

I have a device attached to my Android phone.

I need to send 2 commands (2 bytes) to that device.

The device responds:

- COMMAND 1: at the first command respond with random gibberish (it might send nothing at all);
- COMMAND 2: at the second command with the meaningful stream of bytes.

Now the problem is that I do not know what the device will send after the COMMAND 1,
and I really do  not care.

I care about what I receive after COMMAND 2.

Now the problem is: how do I get rid from the inputstream of all the possible meaningless stuff I could get after COMMAND 1?

Is there a way to "clean" the inputstream?

Comment: Protocol of communications is like this then?

1.You send1 command.
2.1 response
3.You send 2 command
4.2 response

Comment: how about https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#skip%28long%29 ?

Comment: @Jure mmm not sure I understand Jure

Comment: @Frozendragon thanks Frozen, but I do not know how much stuff (gibberish) I might get after command 1 :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a tricky problem.  And the core trickiness is that you don't know how much gibberish "COMMAND 1" is going to produce.

You could do something like this:

```
// send command 1
// while (is.available() > 0) {
//     is.read()
// }
```

but that *may not be reliable*.  The problem is that if the device produces the gibberish slowly or in a bursty fashion, `is.available()` call *could* return zero before the device has finished outputting the gibberish.

So a better approach may be to either wait for a short period before starting the read loop, or put a timer of some kind on the loop ... so that you keep trying for a period after the last time that `available()` returns a non-zero value.

Clearly, you will need to experiment to figure out which approach works best.

---

The other alternative (better IMO) is to figure out what the gibberish means ... at least to the degree that you can tell definitively when it has stopped.

Comment: Good answer, my solution: I send COMMAND 1, wait, clear gibberish and then send COMMAND 2. +1 Anyway :-) , because it's a very good answer! THANKS!!!! What do you think of my approach?

Comment: In a situation like this, it all depends on the characteristics of the device.  If the behaviour of the device is such that your solution works reliably, then it is a good-enough solution.  That's what really matters.

Comment: Thanks really helped with my use case:

```public void flush() throws IOException {
  InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
  // ObjectInputStream dIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
  while (is.available() > 0)
   is.read();
 }```

Answer (score 2):

Refining my answer: You can either ignore a defined number of bytes of an input stream names `response` by

```
response.skip(n);
```

(where n is the number of bytes)

or as @Jure already mentioned, you can ignore the *complete* content of a stream by either completely reading and ignoring it or do a

```
response.skip(response.available());
```

Just have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#skip(long) and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available() .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of response from first command just read what you get on inputstream, but do nothing with it. And when you will read after second command you will get only second response.
Like this(example based on java ME):

```
outputstream.write(1command); //you send your first command
while(inputstream.availabele() > 0) //you read the response you get but you don't do nothing with it
{
   inputstream.read();
}
outputstream.write(2command); //you send the second command
while(inputstream.availabele() > 0) //you again read the response
{
   inputstream.read(); //save this data to variable you want
}
```